# Windows & Forms Authentication in Integrated Pipeline mode

Tags: forms-authentication, iis-7.5, windows-authentication, integrated-pipeline-mode

I had a site hosted in IIS 7.5 with the Classic pipeline. I had set the authentication for that site so that Windows and Forms authentication were enabled, but anonymous was not. This caused the user to be prompted the first time they came to the site for the Windows authentication. Then it would bring them to the site as normal. This was set up for a review site for our client to be able to exclusively access that site without anyone accidentally stumbling upon it.

I just updated that site and moved it over to the Integrated pipeline. Now, when you first go to the site, it still prompts for the Windows authentication, but then it brings you to the loginUrl specified in the web.config for the forms authentication, which is not what I want.

From what I understand about the 2 pipelines' affects on authentication, I believe it is the issue. Is there any way I can replicate the behavior I was originally getting in Classic mode now that I've switched to Integrated mode?